# Drag and drop external object into CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I see in CKEitor 4.5 there is a new drag and drop system. I would like to drop external DIVs or SPANs into my CkEditor and have them turn into "placeholders" "fake objects" or "protected source" objects. I.e., the dropped object should turn into arbitrary HTML that's related to the content.

The available demos seem to be about uploading content, but this is different and I'd appreciate a demo ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. CKEditor 4.5 is in the beta phase at the moment, what means there is no tutorials yet, but here is sample how to do it.

First, you need to mark your data on `dragstart`. You can simple set `text`:

```
dragstart( evt ) {
  evt.dataTransfer.setData( 'text', 'foo' );
} );
```

But then you need to make your text unique, otherwise every time someone drop `foo` it will be recognize as your container.

I prefer to use CKEditor data transfer facade, which let you use custom data type on every browser (including IE 8+):

```
dragstart( evt ) {
  var evt = { data: { $: $evt } }; // Create CKEditor event.

  CKEDITOR.plugins.clipboard.initDragDataTransfer( evt );
  evt.data.dataTransfer.setData( 'mydatatype', true );

  // Some text need to be set, otherwise drop event will not be fired.
  evt.data.dataTransfer.setData( 'text', 'x' );
} );
```

Then in the CKEDITOR you can recognize this data and set your html to be dropped. You can replace dropped content whit whatever you need. Simple set `text/html` data in the drop event:

```
editor.on( 'drop', function( evt ) {
  var dataTransfer = evt.data.dataTransfer;

  if ( dataTransfer.getData( 'mydatatype' ) ) {
    dataTransfer.setData( 'text/html', '<div>Bar</div>' );
  }
} );
```

You can find working sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/oqzy8dog/3/

Comment: Well, three and a half years later apparently there are still no tutorial on this, or at least I wasn't able to find one, but with this example I was able to get started - very useful, thank you!